# Save to Database when someone updates notes field in html table (django)

Tags: html, django

I have found many answers to this on SO but my understanding of all of this is still too new to be able to understand how to implement so just posting my exact question:

I have a table which is a filtered view of my database that shows up on one page of my app. It has a notes column where each cell uses content-id-editable. I want to add a save button and when someone wishes to save that particular notes section cell I want them to be able to press "save" and have the updated cell post to the database.

UPDATED QUESTION:

I have made an attempt at using AJAX to push the data to the database (based on @rastawolf's answer) but I haven't made much progress and everything online seems to be geared toward inputting an entire form instead of one column of a table. Here's where I'm at so far:

notes.js:

```
function saveNoteAjax() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Users/justinbenfit/territorymanagerpython/homepage/views.py/notes',
        data: {note: document.getElementById('notes').value,}
    })
}

async function SaveLoadNote(){
    await saveNoteAjax()
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Users/justinbenfit/territorymanagerpython/homepage/views.py/notes',
            data: {note: document.getElementById('notes').value}
            
    })
    let location = "/Users/justinbenfit/territorymanagerpython/homepage/", """I don't have any idea how to make the page refresh"""
    location.reload() 

}
```

detail.hmtl:

```
<table class= "content-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Distributor</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Brand</th>
                            <th>Cell</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Notes</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        {% for tm in territory_manager %}
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{ tm.Name }}</td>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{ tm.Distributor }}</td>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{ tm.State }}</td>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{ tm.Brand }}</td>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{ tm.Cell }}</td>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{ tm.Email }}</td>
                            <td id='notes' contenteditable="True">{{ tm.Notes }}</td>
                            <td><input type='submit', align="right" value='Update' class='btn btn-primary'></td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        {% else %}
                        <h2>No Results for: {{ state }} </h2>
                    {% endif %}
                        </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="assets/js/notes.js"></script>        
            </body>

</html>
```

views.py:

```
def notes(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
      note = request.POST['note']
      updatedNote = TM.objects.update(note) #how is the database supposed to know which tm's notes field to update? How do I pass that information in here?
      return render(request, 'homepage/detail.html', {"note": updatedNote})
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend setting it up this way as the page will refresh every time someone saves a note...

Why don't you instead send the POST data via AJAX?

You will need to write a JavaScript function that you can call when your button is clicked.

You can do something simple like...

**Notes.js**

```
function saveNoteAjax() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'your route to the function notes function in views.py',
        data: {note: document.getElementById('yourNotesInput_ID').value}
    })
}

async function SaveLoadNote(){
   await saveNoteAjax()
   *use another Ajax call to get the new notes from the DB*
   *insert some function to refresh the notes on-screen*
}
```

**views.py**

```
def notes(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
      note = request.POST['note']
      *insert your code for updating your DB table*
      return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: Thank you! So do I need to create a forms.py file for this method to work?

Comment: You don't need to create a `forms.py` as you could accomplish everything via HTML and Javascript. The client has to communicate with the server, and the server with the DB. If you only wish to save a new note to the DB and not display it to the user, a simple submit without AJAX would be my approach. If your intention is to submit a note, and have the 'note section' of the page refresh and display the new note to the user, I would highly reccomend AJAX or fetch api.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help thus far. I have tried to fill in the sections that you left for me to figure out and I'm just not wrapping my head around it and nothing online seems geared toward using AJAX to update just one cell in a dynamic (for loop generated) table. I have updated my answer to show my progress. If you are willing I would appreciate some more direction. Thanks!

Comment: The url route in the Ajax call should be the route that you declared in your `urls.py` and it is a relative route i.e.(if you are on 'myWebsite.com/managers' when you make the call and your intended route is /managers/, you can leave this parameter blank because you are already there). The `data` parameter is used to PASS data to the server that you will need in order to retrieve the data you are looking for i.e.(someone selects a territory manager, you PASS that info to the server via AJAX, filter on territory manager, and retrieve the notes). Finally, the functions are not being called...

Comment: I would recommend reviewing AJAX calls if you intend to use this method. Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the pointers. I will review the docs and see if I can figure it out. @rastawolf

Comment: Hi @rastawolf. I have spent the last few days trying to solve the problem based on the link you sent. The link displays how to use the `XMLHttpRequest` object which I'm not having anymore luck with. I noticed that the orginal answer you posted appears to be using the JQuery library. Is that correct? After reviewing the link you sent your original answer seems easier than the XML request object. Is it indeed jquery? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want AJAX, you could make your entire table into a Django model formset. Each notes field would be an input element. To get started, `{{form.notes}}`. Once it's working you can change your html to render the and style the form field any way you want).  The other non-editable fields would be accessed with `{{form.instance.fieldname}}`

The differemce would be that the user would need to explicitly update after making changes, i.e.  you need an Update button to submit the change(s)

Formsets and model formsets look complicated to start with, but they aren't really once you have done a few on them!